# Unity 3D or Gnome 3 doesn't work with Intel card (switchable graphics)

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, 64-bit

I have a system with switchable graphics: an ATI Radeon HD 6770M, and an Intel HD 3000. I installed the driver from additional-drivers. The Post Release Updates one was unable to be installed, so I simply installed the other one.

Everything works fine with the AMD card.

The problem is when I switch to the Intel card to get more battery life, I have to use Gnome classic or Unity 2D. Unity 3D or Gnome 3 does not work. It just shows my desktop background and nothing else.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.

EDIT: I have uninstalled Unity, so my objective is to get Gnome 3 working with my Intel card.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

It's quite long, so I'm not going to write it out here, just look at the link. My Intel Graphics is working now!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.